# Stored Procedure not visible in MAMP

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, laravel-5, phpmyadmin, migration

Im facing this weird problem that I am trying to resolve since the last couple of hours,

I have created my database via migrations in Laravel 5.2, when I am trying to create a stored procedure with a migration it successfully runs the migration but when I try to view the stored procedure in phpMyAdmin under Routines it says "There are no routines to display" and when I try to run the migration again it gives me an error that a routine with this name already exists.

Then I tried to manually create a stored procedure through phpMyAdmin, when I press Go it shows me that he procedure has been successfully created, but when I try to view my procedure under Routines it again says "There are no routines to display" and if I try to create the same stored procedure via phpMyAdmin it shows me the same error that a routine with this name already exists.

To see if my stored procedure ever gets created I exported the database but there was no sign of a procedure in the .sql file, I do not know why it shows me the error that this stored procedure already exists.

Comment: Is this a user permission issue i.e. you create the proceedure under one account then try and view it under another?

Comment: no thats not the problem I have given all privileges to all users